# PHP Mail Error in Microsoft WebMatrix

Tags: php, sendmail

I am a newbie in Web Development an I am currently learning PHP and MySQL. I have read HeadFirst PHP and MySQL, and tried the examples. But The PHP Mail() function doesn't work on my Local Machine. I have tried the script on a web server but nothing happens, the mail isn't sent. Please Help me. I have configured the PHP.INI file to send emails but still the problem persists.

```
<?php
$to = "me@me.com";
$sub = "hello";
$msg = "Hello, how are you?";
//Mail Function
mail($to,$sub,$msg);
?>
```

I am using WebMatrix with PHP 5.2 installed. Please help me, I am trying out this one since last 2 hours! I am stuck!

Comment: i have the same head first book, I couldn't get it to send mail from my local machine either. Just upload the file to your server and it will work fine. It did for me

Answer (score 4):

mail() uses 'localhost' to send - it generally assumes it's on Linux.

You will need to aquire a basic SMTP server and run it on windows, OR you may be able to use the SMTP server of your're ISP.

Whichever option, you will need to edit your php.ini, you will find:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP =
```

you must set SMTP to the ip/port of a mailserver - again wither run one locally or use your ISP.

**EDIT**

You could try this approach - I have personally never tried to use GMail for sending: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-pear-mail-packege-support-security-through-ssl-586976/

Comment: So, can I use GMail or any web service to send mail? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 3):

> But The PHP Mail() function doesn't work

Yes it does. The problem is either with how you configured PHP or with the MTA you configured it to use. You'd need to provide details of both for us to understand why mail is not getting sent.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer also is applicable to those who use a simulated local IIS e.g. the WebMatrix on IIS Express users who reside within a corporate network with a SMTP machine available. 
To be able to send emails out from within it one needs to edit the PHP.INI file (found typically in \Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v5.3) and replace 'localhost' with the SMTP server IP or DNS name.